# Workflowing an InfoPath form

Tags: workflow, infopath

I have an InfoPath form that requires workflow.  The form is build from a cXML schema in BizTalk,then dropped into a forms library for workflow.  The user opens the infopath form, reviews and picks one of several options: re-submit, archive, escalate, etc.

My question is how best to workflow this?  Do you have the buttons on the form update a status/action field, and have the workflow listen for an onChange event?

Can you update a property on the library, that is not a field on the form? for example, if status is not part of the form schema, but is a column on the document library.

How do ye typically do this?

thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You don't necessarily need to create an event listener for the forms library.  SharePoint workflows can be configured to start only whenever a document in the library is modified.

Hope that helps.

-Ash